# Is there a way to get ipython autocompletion when piping a pandas dataframe to a function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, autocomplete, ipython, jedi

For example, if I have a pipe function:

```py
def process_data(weighting, period, threshold):
    # do stuff
```

Can I get autocompletion on the process data arguments?

There are a lot of arguments to remember and I would like to make sure they get passed in correctly. In ipython, the function can autocomplete to show me the keyword args which is really neat, but I would like it to do this when piping a pandas dataframe too!

[image]

[image]

I don't see how this would be possible, but then again, I'm truly in awe of ipython and all its greatness. So, is this possible? If not, are there other hacks that people have come up with?

Answer (score 0):

Install the pyreadline library.

```sh
$ pip install pyreadline
```

**Update:**

It seems like this problem is specific to some versions of ipython. The solution is the following:
Run below command from the terminal:

```sh
$ ipython profile create
```

It will create a default profile at `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

Now edit this `ipython_config.py` and add the below lines and it will solve the issue.

```py
c = get_config()
c.Completer.use_jedi = False
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2435
- https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but could you please elaborate?

Comment: install the package using pip package manager using the command above, then the autocomplete suggestions should show up in ipython

Comment: but i'm not having trouble with autocompletion. it already works, just not for my use case.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. i tried your suggestion but still not getting the completion for the piped function. it's fine, i think what i'm asking for is just not doable as ipython isn't able to interpret the parameters to my piped function as autocomplete options to `.pipe()`